# Which google font is closest to this?

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts, google

Can someone help me to find a google font closest to this one?

[image]

Comment: Hi alina, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I downvoted because I think this question could be greatly improved if you add a few things. First, it might help if you tell us what typeface this is. Second, please show us what Google fonts you have considered and why they fall short. Please [edit] this info into the question. Thanks for your effort! If you have any questions about how this site works, have a look at the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation allows that (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Online Tool to Find Closest Google Font](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26365/online-tool-to-find-closest-google-font)

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [Merriweather](http://google.com/fonts/specimen/Merriweather) myself. It seems to be the closest of the bunch.

[image: Merriweather 400]

Comment: ...unless you value x-height: the font shown by the OP has a classically small x-height, while Merriweather has a relatively large one. Rather nice find, though.

Comment: Yes you're right, I should have factored that. I guess that makes quite a bit of difference, thanks for pointing it out.