# Suggestion for Alternate Font Option?

Tags: fonts, typography, logo, branding

Would greatly appreciate your help. I had a freelance graphic designer create the below logo for me. It is for a higher-end real estate photography and marketing company in the Los Angeles area, and I want the brand to emphasize the use of technology as well as a sophisticated approach *(read: wide-tracked sans-serif type).*

[image]

It was set in Novecento Wide Light and the type was stroked to compensate for its thin weight. I feel like the font is "almost" there but not quite. Any recommendations as to alternate font options that would create the look and feel I'm after? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a baz-illion san serif typefaces out there. Many are kind of close to Novecentro. I've always felt Novacentro was a tad bit ugly and "rugged" where a font is concerned.

A few san serifs I like:

- [Clan Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/clan-pro/)
- [Sarre](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/stereotypes/sarre/)
- [RBNo2.1](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rene-bieder/rbno2-1/)
- [Rama Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/flat-it/rama-gothic/)
- [Myriad Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/myriad/)
- [Humanist](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/humnst-777/)
- [Helvetica Neue](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/)
- [Futura](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/futura/)

It ultimately comes down to a matter of preference. If you want to mirror the very round aspect of the main typeface (I think Avant Garde maybe?), then maybe leaning towards, Myriad, Humanist, Helvetica Neue, and Futura would be best.

Comment: Some good choices there. For a more "friendly" modern feel I've been fascinated with [Ropa Soft Pro's][1] rounded softness. The italics are also quite interesting with their ink traps.
[1]: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lettersoup/ropa-soft-pro/

Answer (score 0):

For a free, modern alternative to Helvetica Neue (mentioned by Scott), with some oblique cuts (like Novecento Wide), see [**Liberation Sans / Arimo**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8845).